# Choose single float from a list

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I have a list of floats being generated starting from 0 to 1 in an increasing order. I need to do something with selected floats, for instance one near 0.25, 0.5, 0.75. But the generated floats can have any number of decimal places, and repeats, like
..........0.50001, 0.51125, 0.57466459, 0.5925, 0.5925, 0.634, ..........

I need to select only **ONE** from near 0.5 (any one will do) and likewise at other quarters. A made up example,

```
list_of_floats = my_some_function()
 for i in list_of_floats:
     if i is near 0.5:
        do_something()
```

I tried,

```
list_of_floats = my_some_function()
done_once = False
 for i in list_of_floats:
     if 0.5 < i < 0.6 and done_once is False:
        do_something()
        done_once = True
```

This kind of works for 0.5, but I need to do for other checkpoints (0.25, 0.75 etc) as well. There must be a better way to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start with a list of the checkpoints and some threshold for "near" (either at the top level or paired with each checkpoint if "near" varies for each checkpoint). You can take advantage of the data and checkpoints being sorted in the same order by only ever considering the first checkpoint in the list and popping it off the list when you get a hit:

```
checkpoints = [.25, .5. .75]
for i in list_of_floats:
    if abs(i - checkpoints[0]) < .1:
        do_something()
        checkpoints.pop(0)
    if not checkpoints:
        break
```

Comment: checkpoints.pop(0); That should do it. How will it handle repeats though?

Comment: Repeats in the checkpoints list? Each will be handled once (e.g. if checkpoints is [.1, .1, .5] you'll look for the first two values near to .1). Repeats in the list of floats? It'll only trigger for the first (that's why we pop the checkpoint). Repeat passes through the code? You'll have to reconstruct the checkpoints list each time, otherwise it'll be empty on subsequent passes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you're going for, but it sounds like you're looking for [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html). For instance, if you wanted to find all floats in your array that are within 0.01 of 0.5, you can use:

```
list_of_floats = np.array([0.50001, 0.51125, 0.57466459, 0.5925, 0.5925, 0.634])

# note that atol is the tolerance within which you want to select your floats
>>> list_of_floats[np.isclose(0.5, list_of_floats, atol = 0.01)]
array([0.50001])
```

Or, since you only want one, and any one will do, select the first:

```
>>> list_of_floats[np.isclose(0.5, list_of_floats, atol = 0.01)][0]
0.50001
```

Comment: I think you may have mixed up atol and rtol.

Comment: For this I will need to know the list of floats apriori I guess. But they are being generated in the code in a loop. The one I coded above is a made-up example. np.isclose is a useful find though

Answer (score 0):

if you want the value closest to 0.5, then something like this might get you there:

```
import numpy

floats = numpy.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.48, 0.51, 0.55, 0.72, 0.8])

higher = numpy.where(floats > 0.5)
rest = numpy.where(floats[higher] < 0.6)
possibilities = floats[higher][rest]
print(min(possibilities))
>>>0.51
```

Comment: It needs knowledge of list apriori, but floats are being generated in a loop